# Pandas Dataframe multiply with only the right dataframe taking fill_value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multiplication

The `fill_value` argument of `pandas.DataFrame.multiply()` fills missing values in **both** dataframes. However, I'd like to have only missing values filled in the 2nd DataFrame. What would be a good way beyond my hacky solution below?

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, np.nan, 2], 'b':[np.nan, 3, 4]}, index = [1, 2, 3])
>>> df1
     a    b
1  1.0  NaN
2  NaN  3.0
3  2.0  4.0

>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2, np.nan], 'b':[3, np.nan], 'c':[1, 1]}, index = [1, 2])
>>> df2
     a    b    c
1  2.0  3.0  1.0
2  NaN  NaN  1.0
```

I would like to multiply the two DataFrames element-wise, by keeping `df1` as the dominant one so that the resulting shape and `NaN` entries should match `df1`, while filling `NaN`s in `df2` by value 1, to get

```
     a    b
1  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  3.0
3  2.0  4.0
```

The naive solution doesn't work:

```
>>> df1.multiply(df2, fill_value=1)
     a    b    c
1  2.0  3.0  1.0
2  NaN  3.0  1.0
3  2.0  4.0  NaN
```

My hacky solution is to create a matrix with `1`s where `df1` has value, and update by `df2`

```
>>> df3 = df1/df1
>>> df3.update(df2)
>>> df3
     a    b
1  2.0  3.0
2  NaN  1.0
3  1.0  1.0
>>> df1.multiply(df3)
     a    b
1  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  3.0
3  2.0  4.0
```

It just doesn't feel very elegant. Any cool idea on direct manipulation with `df1` and `df2`, hopefully a one-liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) on `df2`:

```
df1.multiply(df2.reindex(df1.index).fillna(1))

     a    b
1  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  3.0
3  2.0  4.0
```

You don't need to explicitly call `multiply` in this case, and can just use `*` for multiplication:

```
df1 * df2.reindex(df1.index).fillna(1)

     a    b
1  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  3.0
3  2.0  4.0
```

Additionally, if you need to align the columns of `df2` with `df1`, use the `columns` parameter of `reindex`:

```
df1 * df2.reindex(index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns).fillna(1)
```

Comment: What happens if `df1` and `df2` have different columns too? What's the best way to _reshape_ `df2` to `df1` on the fly?

Comment: `reindex` allows you to supply columns too, e.g. `df2.reindex(index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)`.

Comment: Ok, great - so the solution is `df1 * df2.reindex(index=df1.index,columns=df1.columns).fillna(1)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative would be to filter the result based on the nulls in `df1`:

```
df1.multiply(df2, fill_value=1)[df1.notnull()]
Out: 
     a    b
1  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  3.0
3  2.0  4.0
```

Comment: What if df2 has extra columns I don't want either? I edited the OP accordingly. Thx.

Comment: @Zhang18 You can filter those columns before the multiplication like this: `df1.multiply(df2[df1.columns], fill_value=1)[df1.notnull()]`

Comment: Thank you. This is a nice solution too.